# How to avoid drag and drop of any mxCell or vertex from a group

Tags: java, swing, jgraphx

I have multiple groups in my graphs containing vertices. I require that the vertices should not move out of the group or parent . Also all my groups are getting superimposed at one place despite giving incremental coordinates. Can anything be done to resolve these problems??

```
mxGraph graph = new mxGraph();
Object parent = graph.getDefaultParent()
graph.beginModel().beginUpdate();
for(Object Card: CardList.size())
{
  int x=300;
  int y =300;
  Object vtx=graph.insertVertex(parent,null,"Side",x,y,20,10);//group Object
  graph.createGroupCell(new Object[] {vtx});
   // A recursive function callwhich creates vertices
     y= y+400;
  x=x+300;
}
mxGraphComponent graphComponent= new mxGraphComponent(graph);
graph.isRemoveCellsFromParent(false);
contentPane.add(graphComponent);
graph.endModel().endUpdate();
   }
```

Comment: 1) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Any problem with the indenting??

Comment: *"Any problem with the indenting??"* Is there any problem with a stuck '?' key? One '?' denotes a question.

Comment: Is it fine now , i'm a newbie to JGraphX and the concept of its graph library